# Trigger not able to delete multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables- Product and BookCopy. Product has a primary key `isbn` and BookCopy has foreign key `bisbn` . I am trying to write a trigger that would delete all the corresponding book copies if original book is deleted. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteCorrespondingCopies
ON Product
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM BookCopy WHERE bisbn IN (SELECT isbn from deleted);
END;
```

It seems like my trigger is fine, because error I am getting is:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Product I am trying to delete has 3 book copies with the same `bisbn` therefore I assume it actually finds them?

Just in case I am putting screenshot of 2 tables structure. Although it doesn't have any special icon, `bisbn` in BookCopy is foreign key.

[image]

Comment: dbo? looks more like you are using SQL Server instead of MySQL..Besides MySQL doesn't support `AS` keyword within de `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html.. SQL server does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: And why dont you use `ON DELETE CASADE`? seems more appropriate to me then a simulating a casade delete with a trigger.

Comment: In addition to Raymond's suggestion, if you have actually set up a foreign key, the constraint should block deletion from occurring before the trigger even gets a chance to fire. The code you've actually shown shouldn't produce the error message you've included so the error is probably arising elsewhere. What's doing the original `delete`? Is there a trigger on `BookCopy`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , @Raymond

I just disabled my trigger. If I run a simple delete query:
`delete from Product where isbn = '000003891';` I get back the same error regarding more than 1 value. This was my query for creation of BookCopy

`create table BookCopy (
copyId varchar(13) primary key not null,
bisbn varchar(13) foreign key references Product (isbn) on delete cascade,
available bit
)`

Product creation query doesn't have `on delete cascade`, could this be an issue? Cascading applied only on foreign key?

Comment: Sounds like multiple triggers on that table then and one or more of the other triggers doesn't properly support `deleted` containing multiple rows. I.e. it has a bug.

Comment: And you have `on delete cascade`, so the trigger you're trying to create is redundant (by the time it fires, the referencing rows in `BookCopy` will have already been removed)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , I have the same `on delete cascade` regarding `Members` and I just tried deleting `Member` without any triggers, so once I delete `Member` , it deletes his address from `MemberAddress` table, and his reservation from `Reservation` table. So this has to be issue with multiple rows being returned. any workaround for that?

Comment: @Kelb56 - since the trigger in your question is irrelevant (not required, doesn't produce the error you're asking about), you need to hunt for the other triggers that are broken. There's insufficient information here for anyone else to help you with that task.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your answers helped me more than you think. I am grateful for that.